# Change UITableView style to groupded from code but no initialization in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Is it feasible to change UITableView style to grouped from within implementation file, but the instance is already defined in storyboard?

So, I write the following code in ViewController.m, where `tableView` is connected through storyboard by ctrl-dragging:

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

However, when I tried to set in `viewDidLoad` method, such as:

```
self.tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
```

I got an error saying `Assignment to readonly property`.

So I wonder whether it is feasible to set it from within implementation file.

I just found [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512417/how-to-change-to-a-grouped-table-view-in-xcode-without-using-interface-builder) to set the attribute, but then I have to initialize the code entirely from scratch.

I also know that I can set it in Attribute Inspector, just like to know how I can set it from within code (but again, the variable is already defined, meaning I can't initialize, if I understand it correctly).

Also, why I got an error `Assignment to readonly property`, despite my NOT defining `readonly` in the `@property` definition? (for your information even if I add `readwrite` to the definition above I still got the same error.)

I use Xcode 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't change the style of a table view after initialization. When you specify the tables style in Interface Builder, you're specifying what style the table will be initialized with.

And as far as the error goes, it isn't referring to the property that you made for your table view, it's referring to the `style` property that the `UITableView` class declares publicly as read-only. The property is then redeclared privately as read-write so that it can be set in the initializer, but either way, you can't modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification!